# react-native-obfuscator crash for a specific file

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to obfuscate my JS code using the lib react-native-obfuscator.
I need to hide the API keys from my code, but I'm getting the following error:

```
error src/services/api.js: function (prevType) {
this.state.exprAllowed = false;

if (prevType === types._let || prevType === types._c...<omitted>...
} could not be cloned. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
```

When I do not obfuscate the file "src/services/api.js" I get the desired result, but it is the most important. My transform.js file is:

```
const obfuscatingTransformer = require("react-native-obfuscator")
const filter = filename => { 
return filename.startsWith("src");
} 

module.exports = obfuscatingTransformer({
obfuscatorOptions:{
compact: true, // default true
controlFlowFlattening: false, // default false
controlFlowFlatteningThreshold: 0.75, // default 0.75
deadCodeInjection: false, // default false
deadCodeInjectionThreshold: 1, // default 0.4
debugProtection: false,  // default false
debugProtectionInterval: false, // default false
disableConsoleOutput: true, 
identifierNamesGenerator: 'hexadecimal', // default hexadecimal
log: false,  // default false
renameGlobals: true, // default false
rotateStringArray: true, // default true
seed: 0,// default 0
selfDefending: false,  // default true: not working if true
shuffleStringArray: true, // default true
sourceMapMode: 'separate', // default seperate
splitStrings: true,  // default false
splitStringsChunckLength: 10, // default 10
stringArray: true, // default true
stringArrayEncoding: 'rc4', // default false
stringArrayThreshold: 0.75, // default 0.8
target: 'browser', // default browser
transformObjectKeys: true, // default false
unicodeEscapeSequence: true
},
upstreamTransformer: require('metro-react-native-babel-transformer'),
emitObfuscatedFiles: false,
enableInDevelopment: false,
filter: filter,
trace: true
```

})

Could someone help me here?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried `react-native-obfuscator` and man it has to many issues.

So I am using `obfuscator-io-metro-plugin` and its working great.

Here I will post my settings for you to see.

in `metro.config.js` Add the following and it will `obfuscator` all string and js code related files.

```js
const jsoMetroPlugin = require("obfuscator-io-metro-plugin")(
  {
    compact: false,
    sourceMap: true,
    controlFlowFlattening: true,
    controlFlowFlatteningThreshold: 1,
    numbersToExpressions: true,
    simplify: true,
    shuffleStringArray: true,
    splitStrings: true,
    stringArrayThreshold: 1,
  },
  {
    runInDev: false /* optional */,
    logObfuscatedFiles: true /* optional generated files will be located at ./.jso */,
    sourceMapLocation:
      "./index.android.bundle.map" /* optional  only works if sourceMap: true in obfuscation option */,
  }
);
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    assetPlugins: ['expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles'],
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
  ...jsoMetroPlugin
};
```

And do not forget to include those below in your github `.ignore` file so it wont be checked in that is if you are using `sourceMap`

```
index.android.bundle.map
.jso/
```

Comment: Hi @Alen.Toma, thank you, it worked!!! I'm getting the obfuscated code, but my objects aren't being obfuscated. Do you have any idea why? I also tried to turn on the parameter "transformObjectKeys: false", but also didn't worked...

Comment: what do you mean objects

Comment: I mean JSON objects, for example: 

var object = {key: "someString"}

I didn't find a way to obfuscate the "key" or "someString" values

Comment: Well its working for me when I have it in `const`, try to have those imported data in a global const variable.

Comment: Hi Alen, I also tried this, but it didn't worked. I got all the file obfuscated but the strings are still there I can be found without difficulty. Do you have any other idea what is going on? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I really do not know. Its working for me even on objects. Where are you checking ? You have to build a release to be able to see inside the apk if it has worked or not.

Comment: I built an APK for release and I checked the .iso folder to see what is inside. But I can see the files obfuscated, but the strings values aren't. I tried to import the json from another file, but didn't worked. Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: Try looking at the setting here https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator

Comment: I tried to find the correct settings to obfuscate my strings, but using the lib on react native, the .jso folder shows all the strings without obfuscation, but using the website "https://obfuscator.io", I was able to get the correct result. I have any idea why I can't do this on react native

Comment: @Allen, when I got the obfuscated files, I can see two folders: src and dist. Which one do you use?

Comment: I believe that the one that gets copied over to the apk is the dist folder. And there you could see that all files are obfuscated. When you look inside the `release.apk/assets/index.android.bundle` file you will see that everything is obfuscated.

Comment: I think I got this. I'm only trying to use the "exclude" parameter but it isn't working... Anyway, thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @Alen.Toma how can I open `index.android.bundle` to see if it's obfuscated?